# How can I use a variable containing an underscore in imap_search?

Tags: php, imap

I want to find an email containing *nick_1998* and I use this syntax:

```
imap_search($mailbox,'BODY "nick_1998"');
```

The code works without underscore. But with the underscore it makes problems. Is there an solution? Any idea?

Comment: What problems? Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: Hi, the mail is not found, I get no error. Would it be "nick1998" are there no problems...